# Input type date need only the number

Tags: php, css, html

Is there a way to just get the first numbers from the input date, for me is it just important to select a amount 1 to 200. I like the scrolling select type more than press the amount.

```
  <form method="POST">
    <label>How much do you want ?</label>
    <input type="date" name="number">
   <button>Send</button>
  </form>
```

The idea is to make it easier for mobile users to select amount with scrolling to the number of amount.

```
<?php echo $_POST['number']; ?>
```

Output 20 (for example ifs user selected 20).

Comment: USE HTML5 patten attribute

Comment: Are you sure a date input is the right type to use here?

Comment: i dun understand for numbers why you chosed type=date for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="number" name="amount" min="1" max="200">
```

try this

EDIT 
you said `like the scrolling select type`for that u need to do something

```
<select name="amount">
<option value="0" selected >select </option>
<option value="1"  >1 </option>

----
so on to 200 
----
<option value="200">200 </option>



</select>
```

i think input is more better :)

Comment: OMG, thanks a a lot, didnt think of dropdown menu -_- this bring me on the right direction.

`<select name="amount">
    <?php for ($a = 1; $a <= 24; $a++) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $a; ?>"><?php echo $a; ?></option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</select>`

Answer (score 2):

```
<label>Product Number:
<input pattern="[0-9]{3}" name="product" type="number" min="1" max="200"/>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML use the `number` type instead of `date`:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="200" step="1" name="number">
```

Your PHP code would be the same but if you wanted to enforce a numeric value you can cast it to an integer:

```
<?php echo (int) $_POST['number']; ?>
```